# How to generate a pdf outline in draft mode using pdflatex?

Tags: pdftex, pdf, draft

I'd like to see the PDF outline (section headers, etc.) despite being in draft mode while using pdflatex. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: \usepackage[final]{hyperref}?

Comment: Nah, doesn't work. Thank, though.